# Run .bat file with administrator privilege at startup

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using Ubuntu and Windows on the same machine, and always have problem with incorrect time when booting into Windows, so I like to execute `w32tm /resync` at startup.

So I'm trying to put this command into a .bat file and place it in the startup folder, but this command requires administrator privilege, so please guide me what to do to make this work.

Thanks.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Schedule it in Task Schedule and tick the required boxes for elevation or run it as system.

Answer (score 9):

[image: check the box]

Just check that box as you set up the task and you are all set!

Comment: Create a task with the command `w32tm /resync` or which task to use?

Comment: You will want to create a .bat with that command inside, like you were talking about. Then just have that run at start up under the `triggers `and `actions` tabs.

Comment: I had to set the event up for "Windows 8.1" on the General tab in my case for the event to run properly.

Answer (score 2):

Place the full path to the command or bat file into the registry under
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

It will run under the system account

Comment: This is the only thing that worked. I tried several solutions from stackoverflow and elsewhere, including scheduled tasks (with running the .bat directly or via `cmd.exe /s start`), creating *.lnk that had "[x] Run as administrator" (calling it via scheduled tasks or via startup folder). Thank you very much, @sonyisda1